# PHP/SQL : "false" value received from database with good query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a php script who ask my database with PDO to verify if some values sent exists. If they exists, the database respond with the id of this line's value.
I tested the query on mysql and it works but the value received is `false`.
This code is only for personal use.
There is the code :

```
<?php
include("../template/pdo.php");
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_utilisateur FROM utilisateur
      WHERE `mail` IN ( ':mail' )
        AND `mdp` IN ( ':mdp' )");
$query->bindParam(':mail', $_GET['identifiant'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':mdp', $_GET['mdp'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$success = $query->execute();

if($success)
{
  $result = $query->fetch();
  var_dump($result); //bool(false) actually
  if($result == false){
    $message = "Try again.";
  }
  else{
    $message = "Congratulation !";
  }
}
```

I tested everything I know :

- `$_GET` is a print/paste from my database table to my url and i have print him
- Printed/pasted on `phpMyAdmin` the query from `PDOStatement::debugDumpParams()` with my `$_GET` values
- `pdo.php` work and used on other scripts
- No log in my logs files.

Someone can help me ? 
Thanks !

Comment: ':mail' command separated ids ??

Comment: Do not quote your placeholders. It will read it as a string instead of placing your value in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Comment: I also question the user of `IN ( )` here.  If these inputs are arrays or comma separated values, you can't bind  them from a single placeholder.

Comment: anyber you're my lord, it works. I knew that a tiny thing was guilty but did't found ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you are testing against a single value use `=`, not `IN`.
- If you have a list of values, several changes are needed.
- The bind code will add quotes, you already have quotes.  Remove your quotes.